# If theory (in some logic) has 2 different models, are these models related in some other way?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let us assume, that we work in sound and complete logic. Let us assume that we have theory Th and 2 different models Mod1 and Mod2 that are interpretations of this theory Th. My question is - what we can say about how Mod1 is related to Mod2? E.g. one can imagine the interpretation of Th into topological spaces (it is possible for some logics), what can we say about the relation betwen the algebraic-topology invariants of those 2 models? Or is there any other, more modest results about relation between the models who are interpretations of the same theory?

Comment: See e.g. Kees Doets, [Basic model theory (CSLI, 1996)](https://books.google.com/books?id=qBjmwAEACAAJ&dq=Kees+Doets+Basic+model+theory&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih9s7Fqof4AhUvQ_EDHVj2BmUQ6AF6BAgIEAI), **Ch.2 Relations Between Models**

Comment: Does my answer address your question?

Comment: Thx, the answer gives the right path into the core of the problem, so, yes, it address my question directly. But I am still seeking (not quite actively though) the more specific answer with the following application in the mind: the collective of neurons of single layer of ("canonicalized") neural network can form the neural manifold and the set-subset structure in this manifold can be the (crisp of fuzzy) model of some (crisp or fuzzy theory) theory. Of course, there can be many such models for one theory and I thought that maybe they are related somehow. I will get back to your answer and...

Comment: ... and try to apply in my situation. Also - such neural manifold can not the exact model but the neural encoding of some exact model. Even more confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're thinking of **complete** theories; or, to put it another way, you're looking for a structural characterization of the relation of **(first-order) elementary equivalence**. Incomplete theories don't generally say much. For example, *any* two structures trivially satisfy the empty theory, and any two groups - however different - are models of the theory of groups.

---

### Main answer

For simplicity let's restrict attention to structures in **relational** languages. In this case, there is in fact a good structural relation we can conclude, namely the existence of an appropriate "back-and-forth family."

We start with the notion of a **partial isomorphism**:

> If $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ are structures in the same language, a partial isomorphism from $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{B}$ is an isomorphism $p:\mathfrak{A}'\cong\mathfrak{B}'$ with $\mathfrak{A}'\subseteq\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}'\subseteq\mathfrak{B}$. We allow structures to be empty here, so that the empty map is always a partial isomorphism between any two structures.

An individual partial isomorphism is basically useless. What we care about are **sets of** partial isomorphisms with intereting "gluing" properties:

> Given structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ in the same language and a linear order $L$, an **$L$-back-and-forth-system for $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$** is an indexed family $(P_l)_{l\in L}$ such that:
>
> - each $P_l$ is a nonempty set of partial isomorphisms from $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{B}$;
> - whenever $l<_Lm$, $p\in P_m$, and $a\in \mathfrak{A}$, there is a $q\in P_l$ with $q\supseteq p$ and $a\in dom(q)$; and
> - whenever $l<_Lm$, $p\in P_m$, and $b\in \mathfrak{B}$, there is a $q\in P_l$ with $q\supseteq p$ and $b\in ran(q)$.

(We can actually generalize this a fair bit, e.g. allow $L$ to be a *partial* order, but that's not super important right now.) Note that $L$-back-and-forth-systems, while not genuine functions, are still "function-like" in many ways; in particular, they can be *composed* in an appropriate way, and the relation "there is an $L$-back-and-forth system between" is an equivalence relation.

The two most important choices of $L$ here are $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^*$ (= $\mathbb{N}$ with the opposite ordering). If there is an $\mathbb{N}^*$-back-and-forth system between $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$, we say $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ are **potentially isomorphic** (and write "$\mathfrak{A}\cong_p\mathfrak{B}$"). It turns out that this is a very useful notion:

> (Karp/Barwise) The following are equivalent for structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ in the same language:
>
> - $\mathfrak{A}\cong_p\mathfrak{B}$.
> - $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ satisfy the same sentences in the infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$.
> - There is a forcing extension of the set-theoretic universe in which $\mathfrak{A}\cong\mathfrak{B}$.

Unfortunately, this overshoots our goal. First-order elementary equivalence corresponds to the usual ordering on $\mathbb{N}$:

> (Fraisse) The following are equivalent for structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ in the same language:
>
> - $\mathfrak{A}\equiv\mathfrak{B}$ (= $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ satisfy the same first-order sentences).
> - There is an $\mathbb{N}$-back-and-forth system between $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$.

(We can also talk - more intuitively, but less efficiently - in terms of *games* and *strategies*, the relevant term here being **Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games**.) Besides being useful for analyzing specific structures and theories, Fraisse's theorem also is a key part of characterizing first-order logic as a whole system - see **Lindstrom's theorem**.

EF-games, and variations on the same (such as **pebble games**), are important in finite model theory; see Libkin, [*Elements of finite model theory*](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf).

---

### Coda

Resisting the temptation to leave well enough alone, let me belatedly take this opportunity to say a bit about *other* logics' elementary equivalence analogue characterizations as well.

Let's start with **second-order logic**. In a sense, $\equiv_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ is reducible to $\equiv$ + powerset: every structure $\mathcal{M}$ has an associated "power structure" $\mathcal{M}^+$ with underlying set $\mathcal{M}\sqcup\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{M})$, such that $$\mathcal{M}\equiv_\mathsf{SOL}\mathcal{N}\quad\iff\mathcal{M}^+\equiv\mathcal{N}^+.$$ This can be used to tweak the back-and-forth characterization of first-order elementary equivalence to work for second-order logic: basically, we want to look at maps between *sets of* elements of the structures involved.

On the other hand, the infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ - just like $\mathsf{FOL}$ but with countable conjunctions and disjunctions allowed - has a more complicated elementary equivalence relation. The relation $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$ does **not** correspond to the existence of an $\omega_1$-back-and-forth system; a game-style characterization of $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$ was introduced by [Vaanaanen and Wang](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0108), but it is more complicated - and in fact it turns out that in a precise sense it is harder for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ to describe its own equivalence relation than it is for $\mathsf{FOL}$ or $\mathsf{SOL}$ (as far as I know this is [due to Farmer Schlutzenberg](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414083/can-mathcall-omega-1-omega-detect-mathcall-omega-1-omega-equiv), and extends to [other infinitary logics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414479/logics-detecting-their-own-equivalence-notions-take-two-mathcall-omega-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well).

There is also an important example of a class of logics *defined* via back-and-forth considerations: Shelah's recently-introduced $\mathbb{L}_\kappa^1$s, for $\kappa$ an appropriate uncountable cardinal. I don't know much about this, but it seems interesting and reinforces the importance of back-and-forth systems; see [these slides of Villaveces](https://avillavecesn.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/modeltheorycmu2021.pdf).

Finally, note that the above are all examples of logics that are substantially stronger than $\mathsf{FOL}$; what about *weaker* logics? An interesting example is provided by **equational logic** (see [these notes of McNulty](https://people.math.sc.edu/mcnulty/alglatvar/equationallogic.pdf)). Birkhoff's HSP theorem gives a characterization of equational equivalence: we have $Th_\mathsf{EqL}(\mathcal{A})\subseteq Th_\mathsf{EqL}(\mathcal{B})$ (= every equation true in $\mathcal{A}$ is also true in $\mathcal{B}$) iff $\mathcal{B}$ is a quotient of a subalgebra of a power of $\mathcal{A}$. Put another way, a class of algberas is equationally axiomatizable iff it is closed under quotients, subalgebras, and products. Interestingly, an analogous result *also* exists for $\mathsf{FOL}$: the Keisler-Shelah theorem states that a class of structures is first-order axiomatizable iff it is closed under ultraproducts and ultralimits. However, while the original HSP theorem is easy to prove, Keisler-Shelah is quite difficult. One natural question here is whether analogous theorems exist for infinitary or higher-order logics. However, it's unclear what "analogous theorem" means exactly in this context.